# Message box in loop to save file does not appear

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet that should be saved on the desktop when the User presses a button. For this I use the following VBA to check if the file already exists on the Desktop:

```
Sub SaveFileOnDesktop()
Do
New_Filename = Application.InputBox("Please type in name for new file?")
If New_Filename = False Then Exit Sub
If Len(Dir("C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & New_Filename & ".xlsm")) = 1 _
Then MsgBox ("File alreday exists. Please change file name.")
Loop Until Len(Dir("C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & New_Filename & ".xlsm")) = 0 Or New_Filename = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & New_Filename & ".xlsm"
MsgBox ("File saved successfully on desktop.")
End Sub
```

Now when the User enters a file name that already exists on the desktop the loop continues. 
Once the user enters another name the loop does stop. This functionality works fine so far.

---

The only issue I have is that the `MsgBox ("File alreday exists. Please change file name.")` does not appear if the user enters an exisitng name into it.

What do I have to change in my code so the message box appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be `True`, thus the `MsgBox` does not appear:

`If Len(Dir("C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & New_Filename & ".xlsm")) = 1`

The length would be at least `10+`, if the file is present or `0` if it is not present. `1` cannot be achieved.

---

To make it appear, write:

`If Len(Dir("C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & New_Filename & ".xlsm")) > 1`

or even:

`If Len(Dir("C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & New_Filename & ".xlsm"))`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Works pefectly.